# Fibonacci squareroot; and r-th root

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, fibonacci-numbers

Define a sequence similar to the Fibonacci sequence:
\begin{eqnarray}
s(1,r) &=& 0\\
s(2,r) &=& 1\\
s(n,r) &=& \left[ \; s(n-1,r) + s(n-2,r) \; \right]^{1/r}
\end{eqnarray}
So if $r=2$, that expression is $\sqrt{s(n-1,r) + s(n-2,r)}$.

I can see numerically that $\lim_{n \to \infty} s(n,r) = 2^{1/(r-1)}$.
So, for $r=2$, the limit is $2$; for $r=4$, the limit is $\sqrt[3]{2}$. [Now corrected by @lulu.]

I'd appreciate a succinct proof.

Comment: Assuming $r>1$, I get that the limit is $2^{1/(r-1)}$  Calling the limit $L(r)$ we see that $L(r)=(2L(r))^{1/r}\implies L(r)^r=2L(r)\implies L(r)=2^{1/(r-1)}$.  Note that this matches your expression when $r=2$ but when $r=4$ I am getting $\sqrt[3] 2$.

Comment: Note:  this isn't quite a full proof.  All this argument shows is that, if the limit exists, it must be of this form.  Shouldn't be too hard to prove that the sequence is increasing and bounded above and that would complete the proof.

Comment: @lulu: You are correct, I had a typo in my calculation. I'll edit.

Comment: @lulu: Very nice, to assume the limit exists and then derive its form.

Comment: You might be able to show the function $f(x,y)=(y,(y+x)^{1/r})$ is Lipschitz with constant $K<1$ with some subset of $\mathbb R^2$ as the domain and range. Some subset containing $(1,1),$ say. Or some other property on $f$ which shows $f^{\circ n}(1,1)$ must converge.

Comment: It doesn’t converge if $r\leq 1,$ of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let

- $f : [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ be any non-decreasing continuous function.
- $u_n$ be the sequence defined by
  $\;u_n = \begin{cases} 0, & n = 0,\\ 1, & n = 1 \\ f(u_{n-1})+f(u_{n-2}), & n \ge 2\end{cases}$

We will assume $f$ and $u_n$ satisfy:

1. the first positive solution of $z = 2f(z)$ exists, let's call it $\alpha$, and $\ge 1$.
2. $u_2 = f(0) + f(1) \ge 1$.

For any $n \ge 2$, if $u_{n-2}, u_{n-1} \le \alpha$, then $f$ non-decreasing implies
$$u_n = f(u_{n-1}) + f(u_{n-2}) \le f(\alpha) + f(\alpha) = \alpha$$
Since $u_0, u_1 \le 1 \le \alpha$, by induction, we find all $u_n \le \alpha$.

Similarly, for any $n \ge 3$, if $u_{n-3} \le u_{n-2} \le u_{n-1}$, we will have

$$u_{n} = f(u_{n-1}) + f(u_{n-2}) \ge f(u_{n-2}) + f(u_{n-3}) = u_{n-1}
$$
In other words,
$$u_{n-3} \le u_{n-2} \le u_{n-1} \implies u_{n-2} \le u_{n-1} \le u_n$$
Since $u_0 \le u_1 \le u_2$, by induction again, we find $u_n \le u_{n+1} \le u_{n+2}$ for all $n$.

Combine above two observations, $u_n$ is a non-decreasing sequence bounded from above by $\alpha$ and below by $u_1 = 1$. This means $\beta \stackrel{def}{=} \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} u_n$ exists and $0 < \beta \le \alpha$. Since $f$ is continuous, we find
$$\beta = \lim_{n\to\infty} u_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} f(u_{n-1}) + f(u_{n-2}) = 2 f(\beta)$$
Together with the fact $\alpha$ is the first positive solution of the equation $z = 2f(z)$, we find $\alpha = \beta$ and hence

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} u_n = \alpha$$

Back to our original problem. Assume $r > 1$, we can take $f(z) = z^{\frac1r}$ and it satisfies the conditions described above with $\alpha = 2^{\frac{r}{r-1}}$. Compare definition of $u_n$ with that of $s(n,r)$, we find $s(n,r) = u_n^{\frac1r}$. As a result,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} s(n,r) = \lim_{n\to\infty} u_n^{\frac1r} = \alpha^{\frac1r} = 2^{\frac{1}{r-1}}$$